# Grizzly JAX-WS and JAX-RS

Tags: jax-rs, jax-ws, grizzly

I created two projects using grizzly.

One is for jax-rs and one for jax-ws.

The code to get the jax-rs running looks like this:

```
    String BASE_URI = "http://localhost:8080/myapp/";
    ResourceConfig rc = new ResourceConfig().packages("za.co.quinn.grizzly.rest");
    HttpServer server = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(URI.create(BASE_URI), rc);
```

The code to get the jax-ws running looks like this:

```
    HttpServer httpServer = new HttpServer();
    ServerConfiguration configuration = httpServer.getServerConfiguration();
    configuration.addHttpHandler(new JaxwsHandler(new AddService()), "/add");
    httpServer.addListener(new NetworkListener("jaxws-listener", "0.0.0.0", 8080));
    httpServer.start();
```

I want to combine the two to get jax-ws and jax-rs working in the same project.

It would have been nice to have a JaxrsHandler which I could just add like so:

```
configuration.addHttpHandler(new JaxrsHandler(new AddAnotherService()), "/addAnother");
```

But no JaxrsHandler exist.

Is there another way I can combine the two?

Comment: It seems you have a handle on the HttpServer creating the Jersey app. What's stopping you from using that for JAX-WS config? You'll want to use the overloaded [`createHttpServer`](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/containers/grizzly2-http/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/grizzly2/httpserver/GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.java#L139) method that accepts a boolean as the last argument, as that is to tell the server not to start when it returns.

Comment: +1 for peeskillet suggestion. You can use the HttpServer returned by Jersey, but I'd suggest to request Jersey to create non-started HttpServer (pass false as one of the params), and then, once all the HttpHandlers are added - start the server (httpServer.start())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved my problem:

```
    Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new JpaPersistModule("myJpaUnit"),
            new ServletModule() {
                @Override
                protected void configureServlets() {
                    bind(new TypeLiteral<ExerciseDao>() {
                    }).to(ExerciseDaoImpl.class);
                }
            });

    ResourceConfig rc = new PackagesResourceConfig("za.co.quinn.ws");
    IoCComponentProviderFactory ioc = new GuiceComponentProviderFactory(rc, injector);

    PersistInitializer initializer = injector.getInstance(PersistInitializer.class);
    HttpServer server = GrizzlyServerFactory.createHttpServer(BASE_URI, rc, ioc);
```